# "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect." error when browsing the website

Tags: asp.net, web, iis-6

I have a website which is developed using VS 2008 IDE. After I have built and published the website, through IIS 6.0, I just browsed it.

But without any progress, it just gave me this error:

> The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.

I have checked names but couldn't figure out what is wrong?

anyone here is experienced with this error before guys?

Comment: Sounds like the virtual directory path is incorrect or pointing at something that actually does not exist, did you verify the virtual directory path on the IIS 6 server where you deployed?

Comment: I have put the website in inetpub/wwwroot. This is also local path of the website. I have not created a virtual directory path for that. Do i really need to create it?

Comment: well, I have tried that creating a virtual directory path, but still same error occurs...

Comment: Is your site configured as an ASP.NET application in IIS?   Also, what is the rest of the error message?  What resource is throwing that error (a link to an image, a markup file, etc)?

Comment: yea, that's right! there is no rest of message as well. actually I have unchecked the option to see the error clearly from Internet Explorer-Tools-Internet Options-Advanced-Browsing-untick friendly messages... after doing this, the error is like that, otherwise it shows as 'http 500 internal server error'

Comment: thanks @jadarnel27! As you asked, it was an ASP.NET application but I have reconfigured the site again and didn't choose ASP.NET version this time. After that, surprisingly It started to work. I couldn't get why it worked this way! I had known before that we had to choose the version all the time.. thanks again for the little hint!

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad I could point you in that right direction =) If you want to provide resolution to this question, you can either post your solution as an answer, or just delete the question (using the delete link below the question). Whatever you want to do.

Comment: @jadarnel27 so what is the difference between defining asp.net version  or not to define it? while I was developing the web project, (by the way, it was not a website, but a web project) the target framework was .net framework 3.5 I'll be glad if you explain it as well.

Comment: @MuzzyB. I'm not sure, because I haven't used IIS 6 much. But an ASP.NET web application project has DLLs, and I assume IIS needs to know which version of the .NET Framework to use to run those DLLs and intepret the aspx files.  So perhaps that's what was wrong - it needs that version info.  I imagine you only saw one choice, because maybe the server just has the one version installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned wrong when i asked the question, it was not a website but a web project. Probably that is not the point. anyway after i have published and deployed in IIS 6.0, i have re-configured its properties. I have not chosen any asp.net version this time. well there was only one option which was v2.0.50727. and then it started to work.

i'll be glad whether defining asp.net version or not for the website that created in IIS is really necessary as well...